# Login redirect. Check user meta and redirect accordingly

Tags: php, redirect, user-meta

I have a function that checks some user meta and then redirects based off that.  I'm pretty sure this was working before I updated everything on my site.

For some reason, now when someone logs in it is always redirecting to `/updated-terms-and-conditions/`.  I have checked the user meta after this happens and its set correctly, so I would expect it to redirect to `/`.

Any ideas?

```
function redirect_login_to_tos($redirect) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $checkout_tos2 = get_user_meta($user_id, 'checkout_tos2', true);
    $checkout_tos3 = get_user_meta($user_id, 'checkout_tos3', true);

    if($checkout_tos2 != 'agreed' || $checkout_tos3 != 'agreed'){
        $redirect = '/updated-terms-and-conditions/';
    }else{
        $redirect = '/';
    }

    return $redirect;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'redirect_login_to_tos');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[woocommerce_login_redirect](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_login_redirect/) is similar to [login_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/) and it has a users parameter.  That means you don't have to use `get_current_user_id()` (which was returning 0 when I tested it).

Instead, replace `get_current_user_id()` with `$user->ID;`.

For example:

```
function redirect_login_to_tos($redirect, $user) {
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    $checkout_tos2 = get_user_meta($user_id, 'checkout_tos2', true);
    $checkout_tos3 = get_user_meta($user_id, 'checkout_tos3', true);

    if($checkout_tos2 != 'agreed' || $checkout_tos3 != 'agreed'){
        $redirect = '/updated-terms-and-conditions/';
    }else{
        $redirect = '/';
    }

    return $redirect;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'redirect_login_to_tos', 10, 2);
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.